# How to start using WIFI automatically when ethernet connection goes down?

Tags: networking, network-manager, internet

I have a broadband setup at home and an another backup connection. The broadband is connected by ethernet cable to my desktop.And the backup connection is connected via wifi. The problem is if my broadband connection is not working and i am connected to backup connection , I wont be able to access the connection until I disable my ethernet connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help, after some adaptation.

I've written a bash script to help with this: `https://github.com/waltinator/net-o-matic` It watches the connection, and when the connection drops, does a user-specified thing to try to reconnect.